# Multi threaded application DeadLock issue with Database

Tags: c#, multithreading, console-application, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I am working with a Multi threaded Console Application, in which each thread basically tries to obtain the TOP 1 "File" row with certain criteria met and locks it.( There is a LockID column which is populated when this happens so that the next thread picks up the next available 'unlocked' 'File' row)

We put a monitor on the SQL Server DB and each time the deadlock happens on 2 queries.

```
SELECT TOP 1 F.Id, F.ContentTypeId, F.ManufacturerId, F.DocumentTypeId, F.Name, F.Description, F.VersionId, F.LastChangedVersionOn, F.ReferenceCount, F.LastChangedReferencesOn, F.LastChangedImageOn, F.ImageSize, F.IsStale, F.InvalidFile, CT.Id, CT.Name, CT.MimeType, CT.IsMimeAttachment, CT.Extensions, CT.CanTrackVersions, CT.UseRemoteSource, CT.FullTextFilter, CT.ContentHandler, V.Id, V.Size, V.Hash, V.Title, DT.Id, DT.Code, DT.Ordinal, DT.Name, DT.PluralName, DT.UrlPart
FROM Docs.Files F
INNER JOIN Docs.ContentTypes CT ON CT.Id = F.ContentTypeId
LEFT JOIN Docs.Versions V ON V.Id = F.VersionId
LEFT JOIN Docs.DocumentTypes DT ON DT.Id = F.DocumentTypeId
WHERE (F.LockId IS NULL OR F.LockedOn < DATEADD(hh,-1,GETUTCDATE()))
AND F.IsStale = 1 AND F.InvalidFile = 0
```

AND

```
(@Id int)UPDATE Docs.Files
SET LastChangedImageOn = GETUTCDATE(), ImageSize = (
    SELECT DATALENGTH(FileImage)
    FROM Docs.FileImages
    WHERE FileId = @Id)
WHERE Id = @Id;
SELECT TOP 1 LastChangedImageOn FROM Docs.Files WHERE Id = @Id
```

The first query is run when a new thread is created and we try to obtain a new 'File' row.

The second query is run when a thread(may be a previously created one) is almost done with processing the 'File' record.Used Transactions on this query. Isolation level was "ReadCommitted".
I'm pretty sure that both the queries aren't trying to access the same "FileID" because two threads would never process the same "FileID" subsequently.
I'm terribly confused as to how I can diagnose this issue. What might be causing the deadlock between these 2 queries?
I'd really really appreciate it if someone could guide me in the right direction. Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: It would be helpful to have more information. - Which database server and engine (if applicable) are you using? - Are you using transactions? P.S. SQL stands for Structured Query Language. There are many DBs that use SQL.

Comment: What are the isolation levels here?

Comment: Also, the only contention I can see is on Docs.Files - with a read and write that could conceivably get snarled... Options: make the read work with less (zero) isolation, so it doesn't take a read lock; or make the read *more* isolate, so it takes a write lock (causing blocking rather than a deadlock). Which sounds preferable?

Comment: @MarcGravell I did use Transactions for the second query in question. The isolation level I used was "ReadCommited". There was no transaction/isolation on the "SELECT" query though.

Comment: @Paul It is a SQL server DB.please see my comment above for other info. Pl let me know if u'd need anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... it's been a while since I did anything with SQL Server. But let's try.

You mention that "two threads would never process the same "FileID" subsequently", how can you be sure of this? Is the ID being fed from a source outside the thread?

Comment: because the row would be locked by the previous thread and the next thread would only pick up the "unlocked" and "unStale" rows.

Comment: It looks like there's a problem there. Is the thread setting those in the database? If so then what about the gap between when the thread starts and when it completes the update? Could another thread have run and received the same fileID?

Comment: Hi. Did you manage to find a solution to your problem and did my questions point you in the right direction?

Comment: Hi @Paul Thanks for checking back. I think it was more of a SQL server issue than  a code issue that was causing the deadlock. The Server was getting overloaded with requests and was running out of memory. Our DBAs did some IO adjustments and it worked OK. Thanks again for checking.

Comment: Ouch! Well I'm glad the problem is found and fixed. :)